# Is everything vegan.automatically halal?

Tags: halal-haram

Assalamu Alaikum Warahmatullahi Wabarakatuhu,

I know that not all vegetarian foods are halal as vegetarians drink alcohol. But vegans don't drink alcohol nor do they eat animals. So I would like to know of all vegan products are halal?

Jazakallah Khair.

Comment: Related: [Are all vegetarian products Halal?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2577/are-all-vegetarian-products-halal)

Comment: Jazakallah Khair

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably, though strictly speaking not necessarily.

Vegan dishes may contain alcohol, which renders them haram. For example, a [baba au rhum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rum_baba) may be made in a vegan form (finding some non-dairy substitute for the whipped cream), but the cake’s saturation in rum makes it haram for Muslims.

That said, these are edge cases. The vast majority of the time, anything which is vegan can safely be assumed to be halal but should always be verified before consumption.